# disable auto-commit for sybase-ASE via python

Tags: python-2.7, sap-ase

Anyone knows how to disable auto-commit on a Sybase-ASE database through python? I am using sybpydb and there doesn't appear to be an option to do so. Researched quite a bit online but can't see a way around. Thanks.

Comment: Start your own transaction?? Are you not already doing it?

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your set-up from unchained mode to chained mode.

> chained mode implicitly begins a transaction before any data-retrieval
>   or modification statement: delete, insert, open, fetch, select, and
>   update. You must still explicitly end the transaction with commit
>   transaction or rollback transaction.
>
> You can set this mode for your current session by turning on the
>   chained option of the set statement:
>
> However, you cannot execute the set chained command within a
>   transaction. To return to the unchained transaction mode, set the
>   chained option to off.

From the [Sybase Documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X82816.htm).